# configurable product options are not added to cart using magento soap api

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap, shopping-cart

I have tried to add a configurable product in using magento soap api.  I am using the following code to add

```
 $product = array(
             'product_id' => 23,    // simple product id
             'sku' => 'H001-Yellow-22',
             'qty' => '1',

            'super_attribute' => Array( [92] => 10, [134] => 3 )  // color is yellow                                                 and
size is 22        

        );
$client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session,$cartId,array($product),'1');
```

Instead of superattribute, i gave like this also

```
'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                'key' => 92,
                'value' => 10
                ),
                1 => array(
                'key' => 134,
                'value' => 3
                )
            )
```

but the options are not added to the cart.  Why the options are not added to the cart?  How the options to be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally my config product has added to cart using magento api

```
$product = array(
            'product_id' => 19,   // config product id
            'sku' => 'H001',
            'qty' => '1',

           'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                'key' => 92,        //attribute id
                'value' => 10       //value
                ),
                1 => array(
                'key' => 134,
                'value' => 3
                )
            )
        );  

$client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session,$cartId, array($product));
```

Comment: how can i get attribute id and value ?

Comment: i use this code but it`s return me this message : please specify product options                                         $product = array(
            'product_id' => 1300,
            'sku' => 'FC006', 
            'qty' => '1',
            'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                  'key' => 152,
                  'value' => 28
                )
            ),
            'bundle_option' => null,
            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
            'links' => null
        );  

            $result=$proxy>shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionID,$cartID,array($product);

Answer (score 3):

It didn't work for me the way described in the accepted answer. So I browsed through the code in magento. It actually works just the same way as adding a product to cart works in the browser:

`$proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    'cart_product.add',
    array(
        $shoppingCartIncrementId,
        [
            [
                'product_id' => 83,
                'qty' => 1,
                'super_attribute' => [
                    '501' => '36', // attributeId => valueId
                    '502' => '41'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    )
);`

The keys of the `super_attribute` array are the attribute IDs of the configurable attributes (e.g. the color attribute's ID). The values are the the value IDs (e.g. the red value's ID).

This is a minimalistic example, I only used the required attributes for the SOAP call. I'm using SOAP API v1, but you could as well do it with SOAP API v2 using `shoppingCartProductAdd`.